Where to find references in Tanach to all 40 sages who transmitted Oral Torah (listed in Mishneh Torah)
Rambam in Mishneh Torah lists forty sages who transmitted Oral Torah. He does not provide references to specific sections in Tanach which tell about these persons (I do realize each of them may be mentioned many times in different places in Tanach). Is there a source that provides references to Tanach matching each sage in this list?  Of course, one can search Tanach in Sefaria for these names, but often different people have the same name, in different books the same person may have different spellings, and it would be a very time consuming thing. I hope someone may have done this work already.
Updated: Yes, of course, I should've said in Tanach and Talmud.

There are only a couple on the list that are going to be hard due to "same name", such as Zecharia, and only a few that don't have an entire book named after them in Tanach :) Also, the only ones in Tanach are going to be up to Ezra, the rest will be found in Mishna and Talmud. I once tried to answer this question on my own and didn't find it too hard, but yes, would be nice to see some works on this. Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for this first question. Enjoy the [tour]

Worth noting that the most recent 18 sages in the Rambam's list are from after the time of Tanach. So there are only 22 whom you would expect to see in Tanach.

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

@Rabbi Kaii
Thank you for the reply. Did you happen to save any notes when you as you wrote, tried to answer this question on your own? By the way, starting from the beginning of the list, I found many references in various Tanach books to פִינְחָס who is at the top of the list after Joshua and Elazar.

@Lzr0 sorry no notes. Hatzlacha

Regarding your update, it was a little difficult to understand. Are you also looking for sources about the post-Biblical sages in Chazalic literature? For that I would recommend Rabbi Aharon Heiman's תולדות תנאים ואמוראים (https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D).

It is not clear what you're asking. Can't you just open a Tanach search site and look up each name?

May as well do this, it's not complicated (although it is time-consuming). Feel free to comment if I've missed any references. I'll add Sefaria links and sources to my notes when I'll have more time. Note: The best tool for such things are concordances. I usually use Herzog College's online concordance, though it has its flaws (in which case I recommend using a printed concordance such as the good ol' Even-Shushan Concordance).1
Edit: It occurred to me as I started linking the verses that at least in the past there was a character limit to SE answers, so it's possible that I may decide to link everyone except David. Will update.

Seventy Elders: Note, there were several groupings of elders, they may not have necessarily always been the same group. The following citations refer to instances where they are stated to number 70: Shemot 24:1, 24:9, 24:14; Bamidbar 11:16-17, 11:24-30.
Elazar: Shemot 6:23, 6:25, 28:1; Vayikra 10:6, 10:12, 10:16; Bamidbar 3:2, 3:4, 3:32, 4:16, 17:2, 17:4, 19:3-4, 20:25-28, 25:7, 25:11, 26:1, 26:3, 26:60, 26:63, 27:2, 27:19, 27:21-22, 31:6, 31:12-13, 31:21, 31:26, 31:29, 31:31, 31:41, 31:51, 31:54, 32:2, 32:28, 34:17; Devarim 10:6; Yehoshua 14:1, 17:4, 19:51, 21:1, 22:13, 22:31-32, 24:33; Shoftim 20:28; Ezra 7:5; Divrei Hayamim 1:5:29-30, 1:6:35 1:9:20, 1:24:1-6.
Pinchas: Shemot 6:25; Bamidbar 25:7-8, 25:11-13, 31:6-12; Yehoshua 22:13, 22:30-32, 24:33; Shoftim 20:28; Tehillim 106:30; Ezra 7:5, 8:2 (probably); Divrei Hayamim 1:5:30, 1:6:35, 1:9:20.
Yehoshua: Shemot 17:9-14, 24:13, 32:17, 33:11; Bamidbar 11:28, 13:8, 13:16, 14:6-9, 14:30, 14:38, 26:65, 27:18, 27:22, 32:12, 32:28, 34:17; Devarim 1:38, 3:21, 3:28, 31:3, 31:7, 31:14, 31:23, 34:9; Basically all of Sefer Yehoshua; Shoftim 1:1, 2:6-8, 2:21, 2:23; Melachim 1:16:34; Divrei Hayamim 1:7:27.
Nameless elders: Presumably, those mentioned in: Yehoshua 7:6, 8:10, 8:33, 23:2, 24:1, 24:31; Shoftim 2:7, 21:16 and perhaps also local elders such as those from Sukkot (Shoftim 8:14-16) and Gilead (Shoftim 11:5-11).
Eli: Shmuel 1:1:3, 1:1:9, 1:1:12-17, 1:1:25, 1:2:11-12, 1:2:20, 1:2:22, 1:2:27, 1:3:1-16, 1:4:4, 1:4:11-16, 1:14:3; Melachim 1:2:27.
Shmuel: Basically all of Shmuel 1; Yirmiyahu 15:1; Tehillim 99:6; Divrei Hayamim 1:6:13, 1:6:18, 1:9:22, 1:11:3, 1:26:28, 1:29:29, 2:35:28.
David (not including mentions of the City of David [עיר דוד] or the House of David [בית דוד, בני דוד] and parallel terms): Most of Shmuel 1-2; Melachim 1:1:1-48, 1:2:1-10-12, 1:2:24, 1:2:26, 1:2:32, 1:2:33, 1:2:44-45, 1:3:3, 1:3:6-7, 1:3:14, 1:5:15-21, 1:6:12, 1:7:51, 1:8:15-26, 1:8:66, 1:9:4-5, 1:9:24, 1:11:4, 1:11:6, 1:11:13, 1:11:15, 1:11:21, 1:11:24, 1:11:27, 1:11:32-39, 1:12:16, 1:14:8, 1:15:3-5, 1:15:11, 2:8:19, 2:11:10, 2:14:3, 2:16:2, 2:18:3, 2:19:34, 2:20:5, 2:21:7, 2:22:2; Yeshayahu 9:6, 16:5, 37:35, 38:5, 55:3; Yirmiyahu 13:13, 17:25, 22:2-4, 23:5, 29:16, 30:9, 33-15-17, 33:21-22, 33:26, 36:30, Yechezkel 34:23-24, 37:24-25; Hoshea 3:5; Amos 6:5; Zecharyah 12:8; Tehillim 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 68, 69, 70, 72, 78:70, 86, 89:4, 89:21, 89:36, 89:50, 101, 103, 108, 109, 110, 122, 124, 131, 132, 133, 138, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145; Mishlei 1:1; Ruth 4:17, 4:22; Kohelet 1:1; Ezra 3:10, 8:2, 8:20; Nechemyah 12:24, 12:36, 12:45-46; Divrei Hayamim 1:2:15, 1:3:1-9, 1:4:31, 1:6:16, 1:7:2, 1:9:22, 1:10:14, 1:11:1-25, 1:12:1, 1:12:9, 1:12:17, 1:12:18-24, 1:12:24, 1:12:32, 1:12:39-40, 1:13:1-13, 1:14:1-17, 1:15:1-29, 1:16:1-2, 1:16:7, 1:16:43, 1:17:1-24, 1:18:1-17, 1:19:2-19, 1:20:1-3, 1:20:7-8, 1:21:1-30, 1:22:1-17, 1:23:1, 1:23:6, 1:23:25-27, 1:24:3, 1:24:31, 1:25:1, 1:26:26, 1:26:31-32, 1:27:18, 1:27:23-24, 1:27:31, 1:28:1-20, 1:29:1-29, 2:1:1, 2:1:4, 2:1:8-9, 2:2:2, 2:2:6, 2:2:13, 2:2:16, 2:3:1, 2:5:1, 2:6:4-10, 2:6:15-17, 2:6:42, 2:7:6, 2:7:10, 2:7:17, 2:8:14, 2:10:16, 2:11:17, 2:11:18, 2:13:5, 2:17:3, 2:21:12, 2:23:9, 2:28:1, 2:29:2, 2:29:25-27, 2:29:30, 2:30:26, 2:33:7, 2:34:2-3, 2:35:3-4, 2:35:15.
Achiyah Ha-Shiloni: Melachim 1:11:29-39, 1:12:15, 1:14:2-18, 1:15:29; Divrei Hayamim 2:9:29, 2:10:15.
Eliyahu: Melachim 1:17, 18, 19, 1:21:17-29, 2:1:3-17, 2:2:1-15, 2:3:11, 2:9:36, 2:10:10, 2:10:17; Malachi 3:23-24; Divrei Hayamim 2:21:12-15.
Elisha: Melachim 1:19:16-21, 2:2:1-22, 2:3:11-14, 2:4:1-38, 2:5:8-25, 2:6:1-12, 2:6:17-21, 2:6:31-33, 2:7:1-2, 2:8:1-14, 2:9:1-3, 2:13:14-21.
Yehoyada Ha-Kohen: Melachim 2:11:4-17, 2:12:3, 2:12:8, 2:12:10; Yirmiyahu 29:26; Divrei Hayamim 2:22:11, 2:23:1-18, 2:24:2-17, 2:24:20-25 and possibly Divrei Hayamim 1:27:34.2
Zecharayahu (ben Yehoyada): Divrei Hayamim 2:24-25.
Hoshea: All of Sefer Hoshea.
Amos: All of Sefer Amos.
Yeshayahu: Melachim 2:19:2-20, 2:20:1-19; All of Sefer Yeshayahu; Divrei Hayamim 2:26:22, 2:32:20-22.
Micha: Yirmiyahu 26:18-19; All of Sefer Micha.
Yoel: All of Sefer Yoel.
Nachum: All of Sefer Nachum.
Chavakuk: All of Sefer Chavakuk.
Tzephanyah: All of Sefer Tzephanyah.
Yirmiyahu: All of Sefer Yirmiyahu; Daniel 9:2; Ezra 1:1; Divrei Hayamim 2:35:25, 2:36:12, 2:36:21-22.
Baruch ben Neriyah: Yirmiyahu 32:12-13, 32:16, 36:4-5, 36:8-10, 36:13-19, 36:26-27, 36:32, 43:3, 43:6, 45:1-2.
Ezra: Ezra 7, 8, 9, 10; Nechemyah 8:1-6, 8:9, 8:13, 12:1, 12:13, 12:26, 12:33, 12:36.
Chaggai: All of Sefer Chaggai; Ezra 5:1, 6:14.
Zecharyah: All of Sefer Zecharyah; Ezra 5:1, 6:14, possibly Nechemyah 12:16.3
Malachi: All of Sefer Malachi.
Daniel: All of Sefer Daniel; possibly Yechezkel 14:14, 14:20, 28:3;4 Nechemyah 10:7.5
Chananyah: Daniel 1:6-7, 1:11-20, 2:17, 2:49, 3:12-16, 3:19-30.
Mishael: Daniel 1:6-7, 1:11-20, 2:17, 2:49, 3:12-16, 3:19-30.
Azaryah: Daniel 1:6-7, 1:11-20, 2:17, 2:49, 3:12-16, 3:19-30.
Nechamyah ben Chachalyah: All of Sefer Nechemyah.
Mordechai: Megillat Esther from 2:5 onwards; possibly Ezra 2:2; Nechemyah 7:7.6
Zerubavel: Chaggai 1:1, 1:12, 1:14, 2:2, 2:4, 2:21, 2:23; Zecharyah 4:6-10; Ezra 2:2, 3:2, 3:8, 4:2-3, 5:2; Nechemyah 7:7, 12:1, 12:47; Divrei Hayamim 1:3:19.
Shimon Ha-Tzaddik/Yadua (?):7 Nechemyah 12:11, 12:22, possibly 10:22.8


1 Citations also include references to the figure as the father or direct ancestor of certain individuals (exempting the case of "the House of David" or the "Sons of David", since these terms appear in a vast number of sources and are more of a title rather than direct reference to the figure.
2 Given that Yehoyada lived to the age of 130, it's possible that he was already alive at the time of Shlomo and is the son of Benayahu referenced here.
3 The verse mentions a Zecharyah as a representative of the house of Ido, both spelled the same as Zecharyah and his father Ido.
4 Some are skeptical of the likelihood that Yechezkel meant Daniel the Judahite. Variant suggestions include Daniel/Kil'av son of David or Dan'el, a mythical Ugaritic wise man.
5 Unclear whether this refers to Daniel the Judahite, Daniel of the sons of Itamar from Nechemyah 8:2, or a third individual altogether.
6 Some commentators disagree with the gemara that Mordechai Bilshan is Mordechai ben Yair from Esther.
7 Some modern scholars suggest that Shimon Ha-Tzaddik should be identified with Yadua. Personally, I agree with this view as it lines well with traditional Jewish chronology, but there are many that disagree.
8 Unclear whether this verse refers to Yadua Ha-Kohen.

Were they from teacher to student? It seems there could be anonymous elders between them. For example, when did Shmuel teach David?

@YDJ Rambam as well as other sources describe each sage as heading a court (e.g., פינחס ובית דינו). In many cases the later head of the court was a student of the previous one, but of course there were other sages, and for instance we don't enough about the period of the Judges. But in the case of Shmuel and David, there is a verse that shows that they met and spoke, and the gemara interprets this to mean that they spent the night planning the Mikdash. https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.19.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Zevachim.54b.3&lang2=bi.

@Harel13 Amazing, thank you! A puzzle for me, Rambam lists only the prophets, but not prophetesses. When under King Joshiah they found sefer Dvarim (or entire Torah) in the Temple, Joshiah asked Hulda the prophetess. And from the text it looks as if when they began reading the sefer it was kind of discovery for them. Not clear who during that period was the bearer of Oral Torah let alone the written Torah?

@Lzr0 Rambam lists the sages who headed or made up the courts of the Beit Din Hagadol, the central court, which were male-only, so of course women wouldn't be included in the list. However, there was no issue with women being prophetesses, and no issue with consulting them. The matter of what happened to Torah study in the time of Josiah is a little complicated and there are different explanations. If you read Hebrew, some relevant reading material: https://rationalbelief.org.il/%D7%9B%D7%91-%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%A7-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA-2/

and: https://rationalbelief.org.il/%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%97%D7%A7%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99/
